# Return a value of class rather than the class itself Python when called

Tags: python-3.3

As I am playing around with classes in Python, I thought the following might be useful. Given:

```
class NewClass:
    def __init__self():
        self.value = 1

new = NewClass()
```

Is there a way that by calling `new`, it would return the `new.value` of `1`, rather than the class itself

```
<__main__.NewClass object at 0x7faa096d38d0>?
```

I assume it might not be possible and people are against it, but I figured I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
class NewClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def Ret(self):

         self.value = 1
         return self.value



new = NewClass().Ret()

print(new)
```

Comment: return a list of variables with return (var1, var2, var3)